# How to change element of list after clicking on it

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to reactJS, and to react-native. I need advice.
I'm having hard time with understanding how to create working action of element of a list.

So. I have parent component which creates tasks in scrollView.

```
        <ScrollView>
          {this.state.tasks.map(function(ele) {
            return (
              <Task
                action={this.handler}
                key={ele.id}
                title={ele.title}
                subtitle={ele.subtitle}
                state={ele.state}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ScrollView>
```

My parent component has state with variable tasks define in constructor.

```
this.state = {
    tasks: [
    { title: "A1", subtitle: "xyz", state: 0, id: 0 },
    { title: "A2", subtitle: "zyx", state: 0, id: 1 }]
}
```

And I want to change state to 1 if specific Task is clicked. I've tried to achived by doing sth like here: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/409/how-to-update-parent-state-from-child-component-in-react
But this is not working.

Comment: Need to see more code - is this an abbreviated format for convenience? Where is handler declared - in the ScrollView component?

Comment: @Mikkel There is no much code beside this, should I paste code of child (Task) componenet, or my "messing around to find solution" version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't provide much context, but basically it should be enough to give the `id` of your specific task in the `handler` call, either by providing it at the lower `Task` component level, or binding it when you're creating the element (by doing something like:

`action={this.handler.bind(this, ele.id)}`

, after which calling `handler()` at the `Task` level already contains the correct id.

Then in your `handler` method you have the `id` at hand, and can then modify the proper task in your state. This is a bit annoying to do in a clean way - you have to take the old task lists and create a new list with the proper task modified. After that you can modify the state with `this.setState(newTaskList)`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have another small question. Addind this line: "action={this.handler.bind(this, ele.id)}" create error "undefind is not an object(evaluating 'this.handler.bind')

Comment: Good point - this is due to being inside an anonymous function, `this` does not actually refer to what you think it refers to, it refers to the function context which is pretty empty.

You need to either make a reference to the original `this` outside the function (`var self = this` and then refer to `self`), or use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thinking further, this might be the core issue you are having. This is a very fundamental and non-trivial issue in React development - see for example [this article](http://reactkungfu.com/2015/07/why-and-how-to-bind-methods-in-your-react-component-classes/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I'm still confused with many things inside javascript, as android dev.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have understood, you want to update the 'state' property in your tasks for particular task. In your handler, you could do something like this :

```
handler(ele) {
  let updatedTasks = this.state.tasks.map((task)=> {
     if(ele.id === task.id) {
        return Object.assign({}, task, {
          state: 1
        });
      } else {
        return task;
      }
   })

  //Set the new state
  this.setState({
     tasks: updatedTasks
  })
}
```

In your ScrollView action should be :

```
 action={(ele) => this.handler(ele)}
```

Comment: I've tried your solution. But elements nothing changes. State change should lead to status change on this list's elements. So maybe it's working but I broke up my code elsewhere, I'll investigate further. I have to find how to log some information firstly.